# A proverb about the belief that "there is a downhill for every uphill"

Tags: expressions, proverbs

Is there any fixed saying in English which can encompass the mesaage that **you should not get proud of what you have or what you are; because as you got famous/wealthy/etc. you might get weak or poor... some day.** [There is a belief in our culture which says: there is no permanent situation for a person in life; your power may disappear one day as you couldn't believe to get what you are now (a powerful one).]

We have a proverb which says:

> - There is a downhill for every uphill. (Literally traslated)

The only equivalent I've come across to in English is:

> - **High places have their precipices**

I had a good research about it, but still I'm not sure if it can encompass these believes or not!

The only thing that I found is that It's quoted in Cassell's Dictionary of Proverbs (London 2003) High places have their precipices.

I know another saying, but still I don't know if you use it in this sense or not:

> - Every tide has its ebb.

So I would appreciate it if you could help me with it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we say

> What goes up, must come down.

Also, to suggest it's a good idea to be nice to people when you are successful:

> Be careful who you stand on, on your way up, as you will meet them on the way down

In the other direction, to suggest those down will someday rise:

> Every dog has his/its day

(Edit) Neither of your examples is in common use (or at least, I've never heard them) and may or may not apply to this situation.

*"Every uphill has its downhill"* makes perfect sense, but it's not as idiomatic as *"What goes up must come down."*

Rather than the inevitable reversal of fortune, *"High places have their precipices"* implies that success brings great risk.  It's more of a *warning* than a *prediction*.  For example celebrity brings renown, but also scrutiny.  A person who is not famous can usually do what they like (within the limits of the law, of course), but a single misstep from a famous person -- or even exposure of past missteps -- can destroy a career and bring a lifetime of shame.

*"Every tide has its ebb"* implies that the "wave" of good fortune that brings success will eventually subside.  Again, I see it as a warning to the successful not to rely on things like good luck or public approval, but instead to think about long-term strategies based on less ephemeral factors.

Comment: Thank you @Andrew, but what about my suggestions? Are they archaic or some translations or what? I was wondering if you let me know anout them too.

Comment: @A-friend  Please see my edits.

Comment: Than you very much @Andrew. Perfect answer. Although what I meant was absolutely contrary to "Every downhill has its uphill"; while I said: Every uphill has its downhill". ;)

Comment: @A-friend  Yes, you're right.  I fixed it.  I guess I'm just an optimist at heart.  :)